# How can I set the maxDate on a calendar if I have a String?

Tags: java, android, date-parsing, android-date

How can I set the maximum date of a calendar using `setMaxDate` if I have the date with the format `dd/mm/yyy`?

I'm developing for Android.

Comment: What sort of calendar is that?

Comment: Your Question is incomplete. The `setMaxDate` method is on what class? Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean `android.widget.DatePicker.setMaxDate`.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u");
    String maxDateString = "21/12/2019";
    long maxDateInMillis = LocalDate.parse(maxDateString, dateFormatter)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
    yourDatePicker.setMaxDate(maxDateInMillis);
```

In my time zone the example date used above, 21/12/2019, produces a `maxDateInMillis` of 1 576 882 800 000. According to Epoch Converter (link at the bottom) this means

> **Your time zone:** lørdag d. 21. december 2019 kl. 00:00:00 GMT+01:00

According to the linked documentation `DatePicker` uses the device time zone.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [`DatePicker.setMaxDate` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long))
- [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.